# How to enable buttons when a the value of a variable changes in Html/Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two simple buttons, disabled by deafault:

```
<button type="button" id="validate" style="position: absolute; left:1250px; top:500px; height:20px;"> Validate </button>
<button type="button" id="review" style="position: absolute; left:1250px; top:530px; height:20px;"> Review</button>
```

and a boolean variable that changes from false to true when it reaches the value of the number of a pdf pages. This code is written in another html file:

```
const showNextPage = () => {
    if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
        return;
    }
    pageNum++;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
    if (pageNum == pdfDoc.numPages) {
        end = true;
    }
};
```

in the main page:

```
//code

if (end) {
            document.getElementById("validate").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("review").disabled = false;
        }
```

so the question is simple: when the variable becomes true the buttons don't change, so what can i do? Are there any options to trigger a function/some code when the value of the variable changes?

Comment: How is the value actually changed? Post a [mcve] so that we can see the issue please

Comment: Sorry, i have changed my post. Basically i have a function that check when a user arrives at the end of a pdf file. When it does, the variable becomes true. But when it appens, the button remain the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the function or if it's correctly validating that you are in the last page but you should change the disabled state to true in order to disable the button.

```
document.getElementById("validate").disabled = true;
```

Comment: My goal is to enable the button when the varisable changes

Comment: you need to fire a function for it to happen otherwise it won't update the state when the showNextPage function is fired